# Where is my macOS installer file located?

Tags: macos, finder

I am looking for the installer for the OS X operating system installer I downloaded. Where is it stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

#### in the `/Applications` folder

Comment: ...until you install it, then it's gone, so make a copy to another location first, in case you need it again.

Comment: While Apple's support documents say the the installers wind up in `/Applications`, this isn't always the case. I just downloaded the installer, and it's available to use in Software Update, but it isn't in `/Applications/` or findable by Spotlight. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372