# Names and location of .dmg files for OS X installation

Tags: macbook-pro, install, mount, dmg

I believe a file was download and mounted to a director under Applications:

```
cd /Applications
ls -l | grep -i install
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  102 Nov  2 23:55 Install macOS High Sierra.app
```

Is there BASH command that can reveal the name and location of the mounted file?  This question is significant different from: [Where is my macOS installer file located?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252099/where-is-my-macos-installer-file-located)  It would not surprise me if it were a .dmg file, but I would think that it is possible to mount other file types such as .iso

I am seeking the location and name of the file that is mounted to the directory of the Application: not the directory name itself (which is quoted above).

## UPDATE

As indicated by the responses, a .dmg was not mounted.  I suspect the OS installation file located at:

```
ls -l  /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/SharedSupport

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel         328 Nov  2 23:55 AppleDiagnostics.chunklist
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel     2865866 Nov  2 23:55 AppleDiagnostics.dmg
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel        1984 Nov  2 23:55 BaseSystem.chunklist
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel   486219126 Nov  2 23:55 BaseSystem.dmg
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  4721786712 Nov  2 23:53 InstallESD.dmg
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel        1386 Jun 29 01:55 InstallInfo.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

My English is not very well, if you mean the Install macOS High Sierra.app is mounted by a .dmg file .
Then you should be wrong，when you download High Sierra for appstore.
Just downloaded this file “Install macOS High Sierra.app”
There is no mounted operation.

Comment: the file indicated in the answer should be in the applications folder.

Comment: @map1eBluE  Thank you. I think you are correct and will update my original post

Comment: @gatorback After you update you post,i should say it's InstallESD.dmg.
Search it and you can get a lot of results for creating an installer disk.